# Angular 6 , Loading svg doesn't appear in chrome

Tags: angular

I'm trying to load few widgets in Angular 6 , and have created a loading symbol svg , and using following logic to hide and show the loading div , until all widgets are loaded , In firefox , the loading svg appears normally , but in chrome and IE , a blank window appears till all widgets are loaded , if I replace svg with text , even that won't appear in Chrome , here is the code

app.component.html

```
 <div [hidden]="counter >= 3" class="loading-div"> 
       <img src="assets/icons/loading-bee.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
       <span class="loading-bee-txt">Please wait while we retrieve the data.</span>
</div>
  <div>
    <wgt-financials (initialized)="counter = counter + 1"></wgt-financials>
    <wgt-financials (initialized)="counter = counter + 1"></wgt-financials>
    <wgt-financials (initialized)="counter = counter + 1"></wgt-financials>
  </div>
<div>
```

This works perfectly in Firefox , but not in Chrome or IE .

Comment: does it show the image in inspector, under elements in Chrome?

Comment: No , it shows the division ,the image doesn't get loaded , neither the text  , but after all widgets are loaded , image will appear in inspector .

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add 'type' in the img tag. Try removing 'type'.

```
<img src="assets/icons/loading-bee.svg"/>
```

also rather using [hidden] you can use *ngIf

***ngIf vs [hidden]**

*ngIf effectively removes its content from the DOM while [hidden] modifies the display property and only instructs the browser to not show the content but the DOM still contains it.

```
<div *ngIf="counter !> 3 && counter != 3" class="loading-div"> 
   <img src="assets/icons/loading-bee.svg"/>
   <span class="loading-bee-txt">Please wait while we retrieve the data. 
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Even when I use ngIf instead of [hidden] , Chrome still doesn't load the svg .

Comment: It should work. Look at this stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-group-radio-button-disabled-8vwgzk?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: In the question the loading image is loaded till the counter is 3 , quite the opposite of whats there in the url , the div is present till the counter is 3 , and the div has that loading svg at center .

Comment: check the example now..just changed the logic to *ngIf="counter <=3" 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-group-radio-button-disabled-hsexmr?file=app/app.component.html